# Error when trying to derive application db context from IdentityContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to derive application context from IdentityContext so I can use only one context when retrieving the data.

Here is how IdentityContext is defined:

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int> {}
```

And here is application context:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : IdentityContext
{
        //

        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
        { }
        //
}
```

The compiler is complaining about the options variable:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<Application.Data.MyDbContext>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<Application.Data.IdentityContext>'
```

If I use:

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options)
    : base(options)
        { }
```

instead, I get errors when running migrations:

```
λ dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate

More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.
```

And:

```
λ dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context MyDbContext

Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Application.Data.IdentityContext]' while attempting to activate 'Application.Data.MyDbContext'.
```

In Startup.cs I have:

```
 services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
                    options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
                );
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationBlogRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'*

According to this error information, I guess your `IdentityContext` class has a constructor that accepts a parameter of `DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options` as below:

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options) : base(options) 
    { }

    // ...
}
```

So it complains if you invokes `base(options)` within the derived context:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : IdentityContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

}
```

#### How to Solve

Change the constructor of your `IdentityContext` to receive a **`DbContextOptions options`** and make the constructor of `MyDbContext` to accept a **`DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options`**:

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public partial class MyDbContext : IdentityContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

}
```

---

As a side note, you're adding identity services with role as `ApplicationBlogRole` instead of `ApplicationRole`:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationBlogRole>()  // it might cause problems in future.
```

Maybe it should be :

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
```